# Determine publisher of SNS message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-signature, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

Is there a standard mechanism an SNS subscriber could use to verify the identity of the publisher?

My scenario is that several IAM roles and users are allowed to publish to an SNS topic and I want the subscribers to know which one published it.

I know I could use a topic per publisher or have publishers sign each message but I’d prefer a single SNS topic and not require the publishers to do more than just publishing a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of a "publisher". If a set of IAM credentials has permission to publish to a topic, then the API call is permitted. The act of publishing is a function of the account itself, not a user.

You could examine AWS CloudTrail logs to discover *who* made the request, but this is not an effective way to inform recipients of the publisher.